# Ubuntu 14.04 won't install fro USB

Tags: system-installation, usb, windows-xp

I'm a newbie to Linux and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.03.3 LTE on an old XP laptop that would otherwise be discarded. I thought I would erase the old hard drive and do a clean install, but first I wanted to see how it works. The laptop has 1.2 Gb RAM and a Hitachi driver. So far I've had no success.

It took hours to download the >1 Gb Ubuntu 32-bit fi;e with my slow ISP service and I wasn't sure if I had the whole thing as the clock showed it at ~50% and then suddenly was done. How big is that download file?

Since my disk drive in the laptop no longer functions, I used a 32 Gb 3.0 thumb drive that I formatted on my Windows 8.1 Pro desktop with FAT32 and 8192 allocation size, then applied the UUI installer. This magically found my *desktop*.iso file and a recheck of the thumb drive showed 10 file folders and 7 other files:
[Files showing on USB thumb drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE2PU.jpg)

Before the changeover, I deleted a bunch of extraneous programs on the XP and ran Chkdsk on both the C and D drives. (That made it noticeably faster and smoother!) Then I shut down, inserted the thumb drive and started again. F-10 was the key to touch to access my boot options which were:  CD/DVD, FDD, IDE HDD. I select FDD and hit return, which progresses to a blank screen with a cursor at the upper right corner and proceeds no further. Task manager shows it's running, but there is no activity. When booted normally, the old laptop reads the 3.0 USB even though it's 2.0 and shows all the same files, and I get a Ubuntu Menu option screen if I click the wubi.exe file from here.

What's happening here? Did I get a corrupt download? Is my thumb drive improperly formatted or loaded? Is there an incompatibility between the systems? Or something else.

Comment: 50% to 100? Redownload.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a broken iso file due to your saying

Try to download iso via torrent (trust me it's faster) and follow [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

reboot

go to your bios (usually f2 button) and set the order of boot while usb it pluged in, you should see the name of the usb

ubuntu grub2 will comeout and say install ubuntu and follow standart installation process

also i suggest you to install something like lubuntu instead of full unity  ui bc it might be slow with you kinda specs #nooffense

an ssd might speed up things as well, those things are not expensive nowadays like they first comeout

Answer (score 0):

I again downloaded, both the Torrent and the desk versions this time. That really puzzles me because the Torrent is 25 kb and downloads in seconds while the desk file is ~750 mb and took over 2 hours. Are these the same thing or am I not understanding Torrent?

Anyway, using the desk version of Lbuntu, I ran the MD5SUM check and it verified, so I created a USB file using  UUI. After double checking the BIOS in my old laptop for USB boot (FDD), I inserted the thumb drive and started the machine and got the same result. After half an hour I still have a blank screen, even though I saw the thumb drive blinking rapidly and steadily.

I'd really like to try my hand with Linux, but this has become very frustrating. HELP!